# watch expression new value always equals to old value

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

i'm using two [AngularJS Bootstrap-ui Datepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) directives in a single controller.

The code is very simple, the view :

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy" ng-model="startDate" is-open="startDateOpened" min="minDate" max="'2015-06-22'" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event, 'startDateOpened')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy" ng-model="endDate" is-open="endDateOpened" min="minDate" max="'2015-06-22'" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event, 'endDateOpened')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The controller (part of it).

```
  var now = new Date();
  var startDate = $scope.startDate = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), 1); // beginning of month
  var endDate = $scope.endDate = now;

  $scope.$watchCollection('[startDate, endDate]', function (newVals, oldVals) {
    if(!(newVals[0] === oldVals[0] && newVals[1] === oldVals[1])){
      console.log('old values', oldVals);
      console.log('new values', newVals);
      print();
    }
  });

  function print() {
    console.log('startDate !', startDate);
    console.log('endDate !', endDate);
  }

  $scope.open = function($event, name) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope[name] = true;
  };
```

I am assigning two models - `startDate` and `endDate`. Everything looks like it is working fine, when I choose a date in either of the date pickers `$scope.$watchCollection()` callback is fired up but `oldVals` is **always** eqaul to `newVals` so the model doesn't really change (even though the change event listener is fired).

What am I doing wrong ? I'm guessing it's a lack of understanding something basic :)

Thanks

**EDIT**

@Maxim's answer of using deep watch did solve my problem of not going into the `if` statement. Now my other problem is that `print` function inside the callback always prints the old values of `startDate` and `endDate`

Comment: It's a know angular issue. See defect https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$watch` with flag `true` aka deep watch:

```
$scope.$watch('[startDate, endDate]', function (newVals, oldVals) {
    if(!(newVals[0] === oldVals[0] && newVals[1] === oldVals[1])){
      console.log('old values', oldVals);
      console.log('new values', newVals);

      startDate = newVals[0];
      endDate = newVals[1];
    }
  }, true);
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/X160CCfjHN6x456kb1bi?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: brilliant thanks !, that solved my first issue of not going into the `if` statement. Now I have another issue (updated the question), print() function inside the watch prints the old values instead of the new ones. Do you mind explaining why it happens ?

Comment: for me it opens print mode with selected date

Comment: really ? weird, updated your plunker to show the bug : http://plnkr.co/edit/DTZfg3eZuXz6h187b2FC?p=preview

Comment: well, watch doesnt update your model, write it manually: http://plnkr.co/edit/X160CCfjHN6x456kb1bi?p=preview See my edit

Comment: So, if I add a watch, it disables the changing of the model ? didn't know that. Is it somewhere in the docs ?

Comment: $watch only watches, doesn't change,

Comment: I though there's a bidirectional binding between `ng-model=x` and the `$scope.x` expression so everytime the view change, the model change. So $watch just lets you intercept that change, it shouldn't disable the applying the change no ?

Comment: right, like u say `there's a bidirectional binding between ng-model=x and the $scope.x` but $watch only listener on changes. The main goal of $watch is to catch change event for specific model